# SpriteKit scene is blank on iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm creating a SceneKit game and ran into this issue today. The game works how it's supposed to in any iOS 9 and later version, but older versions are a big trouble. What basically game looks like on iOS 8 is just a blank SpriteKit scene (I set the background to be white so it's white) and not rendering anything for some reason. I can't figure out why, anyone knows why that is? I searched for this and haven't found anything. Oh and my deployment target is iOS 7.1 but I don't have any device to test on iOS 7 atm so it might also be an issue there.
I also tried to create a template game project (it even has the iOS 9 dependant code in it, lol) but when I try to run it throws this error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (SKCameraNode)'`. Even if I remove the camera node checkbox it still throws this error, I dunno what to do except drop support for iOS 7 AND 8 which I really don't want to do :(

Comment: code would be helpful

Comment: It's not that different from a Game template, scene is loaded like this in GameViewController:

`if let view = self.view as! SKView?
    {
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MainMenuScene")
        {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .fill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }`

Comment: "not that different" may be different enough. if it were a basic game template it would run on ios8. In fact, why dont you try an empty project and see if it is a problem with your code, or with your Xcode / simulator / device :)

Comment: Well then, what code do you need?

Comment: The SKScene you are trying to load would be a good start :)

Comment: Lmao it turns out the template itself contained code that is only present on iOS 9 and later but even after I commented out that code the app crashes with this error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (SKCameraNode)'

Comment: `SKCameraNode` is not available in iOS 7 ... there are A LOT of features that were added in iOS 8 and 9

Comment: I'm going to make a formal answer now for others' reference <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were probably using features not available to iOS 7 or 8 in your Scene. You can declare certain code blocks as only being activated for certain iOS versions, but if you are using something like a critical features such as a camera node then you may need to increase your deployment target, or use an old-fashioned camera.

This link shows how to implement an old-school camera:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html

and you can use https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/ to convert snippets to Swift if needed.

If you aren't using camera node, try checking in your .sks files for any references to one.. there is an option called 'use camera' that is checked by default for your base Scene in the editor, regardless of whether you have made one:

[image]

I've found that random errors without stack traces to a line of code are typically caused from issues with a .sks or other non-swift file type <.<()

## UPDATE:

After snooping around this seems to be a bug or a problem without a clear solution. My final two solutions would be:

1. Drop iOS 7 and see if iOS 8+ gives you the error (which I thought 8 was the lowest target anyway).. with so few users and features I doubt it is worth supporting 7... but, if you must:
2. Download Xcode 7 (or earlier) and simply make two projects.
   http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3.1/Xcode_7.3.1.dmg

If you take that route, I would suggest developing in XC7 so that way you can share Swift 2.3 code across iOS 9 / 10, or use the built in features to convert to swift 3 later on.

Comment: For features not available in older versions Xcode provides a fix with if available statement - that's what I used. I never used any camera nodes in my project nor I see any in the template but Xcode still complains about that.
But anyway, I appreciate the answer and that Obj-C to Swift converter is very handy, thanks!

Comment: @BuIlDaLiBlE ACTUALLY, try looking in your .sks files... you probably have "use camera" checked!! this may be the reason why.. See my updated answer at the bottom.

Comment: Still throws the same error :(
This is very weird - the template crashes, but my app doesn't (still renders nothing tho).

Comment: @BuIlDaLiBlE you should make a new question / update this one showing the error message so others can see it.

Comment: Added, but I don't think anyone knows the solution tho. The only thing to do is to drop iOS 7 AND 8 but I really don't want to :(

Comment: @BuIlDaLiBlE my final two thoughts on this, which I will add to the answer, is 1: try just upping it to just iOS 8 and see how that works.. iOS 7 is (really) old with few users nowadays. 2: Download xcode 7 or 6 and simply make two projects to release. https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ If you do this I would suggest developing it in the older Xcode swift 2.2 / swift 2.3, because then you can use the conversion tools built in to switch it to swift 3 for your ios 9 / 10 targets. or share your 2.3 code among your 9 / 10 targets

Comment: @BuIlDaLiBlE 8.0 is the built in lowest target for Xcode 8... so you should be able to compile and get your code running for iOS 8 / 9 / 10 from your current codebase.. If you can't get your code running then there is probably an issue in there that you would need to share with us some of the source.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was: I just didn't load the view correctly. And the SKCameraNode error was due to bugged scene - I recreated the .sks file and disabled that checkbox and now it's flawless, works even on iOS 8. Thanks for all your help tho.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is based on a comment by @BuIlDaLiBlE.

1. Delete your .sks file.
2. Add new SpriteKit Scene (.sks) to your project *(optional: name it something else and change the string in your GameViewController.m).*
3. Select your newly created .sks file.
4. In attributes inspector (cmd+alt+7) uncheck "Use Camera Node".

Done.

Have you tried turning it OFF and ON again?